# SOAP returns data, but C# says null response

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, peoplesoft

My C# app won't give me anything but null results from SOAP calls.

We have exposed some PeopleSoft ERP data with a SOAP web service.

I am accessing this SOAP service from a Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET C# app. I have a Service Reference named **CampusDirectoryService** built using the WSDL generated by the ERP.

Here's the C# code:

```
var service = new CampusDirectoryService.TEST_PortTypeClient();
var input = new CampusDirectoryService.InputParameters();
input.First_Name = FirstNameBox.Text;
input.Last_Name = LastNameBox.Text;
var returnData = service.TEST_OP(input);
```

The problem is `returnData` is always null. Through Wireshark, I confirmed that I am in fact getting a valid SOAP response with data. `returnData` should not be null.

I have confirmed correct valid results from the SOAP service through [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), too. Submitting the exact same SOAP request that .NET sends (I copied it out of Wireshark), I get expected results.

Here's the SOAP request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <InputParameters xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas">
      <Last_Name xmlns="">cambre</Last_Name>
      <First_Name xmlns="">aren</First_Name>
    </InputParameters>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here's the SOAP response, with some internal data inside the `ReturnID` element obfuscated or removed:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <root xmlns="http://peoplesoft.com/rootResponse">
         <ReturnID>
            <PRF_Name>Cambre,Aren</PRF_Name>
            <Camp_Email>valid@email.com</Camp_Email>
         </ReturnID>
      </root>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The return type of the `TEST_OP` method is `CampusDirectoryService.rootReturnID[]`.

Why is `returnData` always null?

**UPDATE**
Per a comment, I validated the messages with soapUI. It's squawking on the response with this message:

**line -1: Missing message part with name [{http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas}root]**

Here's the XSD for the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ReturnID">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="PRF_Name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Camp_Email" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is the XSD supposed to validate what's inside `soapenv:Body`, or is it supposed to validate the entire response, including the `soapenv:Envelope` and `soapenv:Body` elements? Looks like soapUI expects the XSD to validate the entire response, not just what's inside `soapenv:Body`.

Here's the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="TEST.1" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/HCM/schemas/TEST.1" xmlns:U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" xmlns:U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/HCM/schemas/TEST.1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy">
   <wsp:UsagePolicy wsdl:Required="true"/>
   <plnk:partnerLinkType name="TEST_PartnerLinkType">
      <plnk:role name="TEST_Provider">
         <plnk:portType name="tns:TEST_PortType"/>
      </plnk:role>
   </plnk:partnerLinkType>
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" schemaLocation="U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1.xsd"/>
         <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas" schemaLocation="U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1.xsd"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1">
      <wsdl:documentation>People Directory</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:part element="U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1:InputParameters" name="parameter"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1">
      <wsdl:documentation>People Directory</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:part element="U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1:root" name="parameter"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="TEST_PortType">
      <wsdl:operation name="TEST_OP">
         <wsdl:documentation>TEST</wsdl:documentation>
         <wsdl:input message="tns:U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1" name="U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1" name="U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="TEST_Binding" type="tns:TEST_PortType">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="TEST_OP">
         <soap:operation soapAction="TEST_OP.v1" style="document"/>
         <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameTokenSecurityPolicyPasswordOptional" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsp:ExactlyOne>
               <wsp:All>
                  <wsse:SecurityToken wsp:Usage="wsp:Required" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                     <wsse:TokenType>wsse:UserNameToken</wsse:TokenType>
                     <Claims>
                        <SubjectName MatchType="wsse:Exact"/>
                        <UsePassword wsp:Usage="wsp:Optional"/>
                     </Claims>
                  </wsse:SecurityToken>
               </wsp:All>
            </wsp:ExactlyOne>
         </wsp:Policy>
         <wsdl:input name="U_IT_CAMDIR_REQUEST_MSG.VERSION_1">
            <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="U_IT_CAMDIR_RESPONSE_MSG.VERSION_1">
            <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="TEST">
      <wsdl:documentation>TEST</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:TEST_Binding" name="TEST_Port">
         <soap:address location="http://domainname.com/longurltoSOAPservicehere"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Have you used soapUI's Validate feature (right click on request or response > Validate (Alt+V)) to make sure the request and response are valid per the WSDL definitions?

Comment: One thing that looks a little off is the xmlns's: the request has one URL for InputParameters, blank for the elements inside it, and then the response has a totally different URL that it uses for all of the elements.  Of course, that might be what your WSDLs define, but it does seem strange.

Comment: @TimS.: Thank you. I am getting this validation error on the response: `line -1: Missing message part with name [{http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas}root]`. Will investigate further.

Comment: @TimS.: I added the XSD. That may help clarify things.

Comment: @TimS.: I think your theory about namespaces is correct. The XMLNS referenced in the response is not mentioned anywhere in the WSDL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a solution to this exact same problem. I found to fix this, there were two main items that had to be configured properly.

1. Make sure to set a namespace on the service (PeopleTools > Integration Broker > Integration Setup > Service). In mine, I used a namespace of:

   ```
   http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/EnterprisePortal/services
   ```
2. It is very important how you create your schemas and the namespaces they use. Each schema requires a special namespace format and message format based on the way PeopleSoft returns the message. For mine, I used the following schemas:

   **Example Request Message Schema:**
   (The request message I used was IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_REQ.V1)

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0"?> 
       <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/EnterprisePortal/services/IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_REQ.V1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
         <xsd:element name="IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_REQ"> 
           <xsd:complexType> 
             <xsd:sequence> 
               <xsd:element name="USER_ID" type="xsd:string"/> 
               <xsd:element name="CHECKLIST_TYPE" type="xsd:string"/> 
               <xsd:element name="CHECKLIST_ID" type="xsd:string"/> 
               <xsd:element name="CHECKLIST_INSTANCE_ID" type="xsd:integer"/> 
             </xsd:sequence> 
           </xsd:complexType> 
         </xsd:element> 
       </xsd:schema>
   ```

   **Example Response Message Schema:**
   (The response message I used was IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RES.V1)

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0"?> 
       <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://peoplesoft.com/IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RESResponse" xmlns:tns="http://peoplesoft.com/IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RESResponse" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
         <xsd:element name="IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RES"> 
           <xsd:complexType> 
             <xsd:sequence> 
               <xsd:element name="PERCENTCOMPLETE" type="xsd:integer"/> 
             </xsd:sequence> 
           </xsd:complexType> 
         </xsd:element> 
       </xsd:schema>
   ```

After I published my Web Service using this information, SoapUI validated both the request and response without an issue.

**Example SOAP Request Message**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:is="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/EnterprisePortal/services/IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_REQ.V1" xmlns:sch="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <is:IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_REQ>
         <is:USER_ID>999999</is:USER_ID>
         <is:CHECKLIST_TYPE>GRP</is:CHECKLIST_TYPE>
         <is:CHECKLIST_ID>NEW_HIRE_CHECKLIST</is:CHECKLIST_ID>
         <is:CHECKLIST_INSTANCE_ID>0</is:CHECKLIST_INSTANCE_ID>
      </is:IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_REQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Example SOAP Response Message**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RES xmlns="http://peoplesoft.com/IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RESResponse">
         <PERCENTCOMPLETE>33</PERCENTCOMPLETE>
      </IS_CL_COMPLETEPERCENTAGE_RES>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle
The issue is resolved by Bug ID 11560861 in PT8.50.00

In PT 8.50 
Steps: 
A. Recreate the schema for the reply message:
1. Peopletools>Integration Broker>Integration Setup>Messages.
2. Choose the COMBO_CF_EDIT_REPLY message.
3. Select the check box "Include Namesapce".
4. Save.

B. Regenerate the WSDL:
1.  Peopletools>Integration Broker>Web Services.
2. Choose the COMBO_CF_EDIT_REQUEST service operation.
3. Continue with the Provide Web Services wizard to generate the WSDL.

Prior to upgrading to 8.50 there are three workaround options: 
A. Modify the WSDL:
1. Generate the WSDL from PeopleTools and then save to file. 
2. Update the WSDL file by modifying the reply to have the entry

to replace the generated: 
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/FSCM/schema/COMBO_CF_EDIT_REPLYResponse">"

3. Then read the WSDL file back into the repository. Peopletools>Integration Broker>Web Services>Consume Web Services.

   OR
   B. Convert the rowset based messages to container/ part rowset messages.
4. To create container/row set parts messages see: 
   PeopleBook: PeopleSoft Integration Broker > Managing Messages>Managing Message Parts
   PeopleBook: PeopleSoft Integration Broker > Managing Messages>Managing Container Messages
5. Modify the Service Operation to reference the Container Messasge.
6. Then generate a new WSDL.
7. Modify the Handler Peoplecode to utilize the methods of Parts message. 
   See: PeopleBook: PeopleCode API Reference > Message Classes> 
   %PART% methods

OR
C. Transform the outbound response messages via XSLT or PeopleCode to match the WSDL is another way to adjust the actual response xmlns to the expected value.